# Access itunes connect for product description.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, loading

I developed one in app purchase application by using this tutorial 
[Ray wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation)
Its working nicely.**But i need to get the product description from the itunes connect at loading time of app** .iam able to display the same in in app purchase page  using following code but not able to do the same in loading time?

```
   - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;

    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *)skProducts[0];

    NSLog(@"naveen -->%@",product.localizedDescription); //will give description of product
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much experience with this, [but I did find something that may or may not help you out](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial/). Go to the link and CTR+F "Retrieving Product List". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer ,thanks for all.

The reason is when app lauch we have to call a methode  didfinishload  in appdelegate.m